# How to pattern match a simple throw when other patterns are present too?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, throw

I am learning erlang and i do not understand how do you pattern match on a `throw` in the `catch` block , when you have both `error`'s and `exit`'s ?

**Module**

```
-module(err).
-compile([debug_info]).
-export([thro/1]).


    thro(F)->
        try F() of
            3->"it worked gt then 3";
            4->"gt then 4";
            5-> throw(44)
    catch
        error:[Y|[Z|X]]->{Y+Z,2}; 
        exit:[X|Y]->{exit,caught,"exiting with code:"++X};
        error:44 -> {"thew on result"} % should it be 44 -> something
    end.
```

**Usage:**

For the first case:  `err:thro(fun()->error([1,2,3])end).`

For the second case: `err:thro(fun()->exit(["A","b"])end).`

Now i want for this case: `err:thro(fun()->5)end).`

Is a throw catched in an `error` pattern , a `exit` pattern or none ? How can i treat my throw when also having other exits /error patterns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a throw catched in an error pattern , a exit pattern or none ?

It's caught in a `throw` pattern, however your `throw()` has to be inside the function F:

```
-module(my).
-compile([export_all]).

go(F)->
    try F() of
        _ -> no_errors
    catch
        error:[Y|[Z|_]]->{Y+Z,2}; 
        exit:[X|_Y]->{exit,caught,"exiting with code:"++X};
        throw:Value -> {throw, Value}
    end.
```

In the shell:

```
27> my:go(fun() -> throw(5) end).
{throw,5}
```

In other words, `try F()` only catches errors that occur inside F, not elsewhere in your code.  If the catch caught errors from here:

```
  5-> throw(44)
```

Then you wouldn't have to write `try F()`, you could just write `F()`.